# Polynomials with least value of n

Tags: polynomials

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with all integer coefficients . If $p (2^{1/5}- 2^{-1/5} )= 2015$ then what is
the least possible value of $n~?$

Comment: Sounds like a competition problem. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried solving this as that by deducing that that the irrational but real part has a conjugate pair of roots . But that lead to a infinite Seires of 2 ^ { 2^k } / 5  for all k = { 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , .... }

Comment: Note that the $2015$ is irrelevant since you are free to choose the constant coefficient of $p$; it's the same as asking for $p(2^{1/5} - 2^{-1/5}) = 0$. Try solving the same problem with $5$ replaced by $2$, then by $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence of fifth roots implies that $n\ge5$. Now note that $a=2^{1/5}-2^{-1/5}$ satisfies
$$a^5=2-5\cdot2^{3/5}+10\cdot2^{1/5}-10\cdot2^{-1/5}+5\cdot2^{-3/5}-\frac12$$
Continuing this way with the expansions of $a^3$ and $a$ you should work out
$$2a^5+10a^3+10a-3=0$$
$$2a^5+10a^3+10a+2012=2015$$
and thus $n=5$.